# Why does Travis says "Your build exited with 1" when it appears to have succeeded?

Tags: travis-ci

[Box Backup build 150](https://travis-ci.org/boxbackup/boxbackup) passed when [built with GCC](https://travis-ci.org/boxbackup/boxbackup/jobs/78052855) but [failed with Clang](https://travis-ci.org/boxbackup/boxbackup/jobs/78052856).

However the last lines of output of the Clang job are:

```
The command "./runtest.pl ALL release" exited with 0.

Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

But if `runtest.pl` exited with status 0 then the whole build should have succeeded, because this is the last command in the travis.yml `script` command line:

```
script: ./bootstrap && ./configure && make && ./runtest.pl ALL debug && ./runtest.pl ALL release
```

Does anyone know what went wrong here and why?

Answer (score 4):

OK, I found out why: the commit in question [changed the travis.yml file](https://github.com/cmorty/boxbackup/commit/14f3df653cedf62b19cf46c3712ebe10c1e6623d) to include two separate script commands. The second one succeeded but the first one failed, so the error was half-way down the log output instead of at the end.